# How to get previous page url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I need privously visited page url in a variable and to find it inside a controller. is there any way to find it?please help me.By using following code 
redirect($this->agent->referrer());

i can redirected to the previous page .but I need this inside  a variable to check.

Comment: Have you simply tried: `$someVariable = $this->agent->referrer();` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this:

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
if ($this->agent->is_referral())
{
    $refer =  $this->agent->referrer();
}
```

In this way you load `user_agent` library, check if there is a referral url and then store It into a variable to use It after

Comment: Would you please tell me for CI4?

Answer (score 8):

It may be helpful

```
$url= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Answer (score 0):

use global $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; but its not trusted php website say that
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php
The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).