# How to get URL before curent URL in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have curent URL like this

http://localhost/matoa-admin/belanja/payment/mtaweb-39384e9f

but how can i get url 3 page before this page in codeigniter

3 page before page is

http://localhost/matoa-admin/produk/koleksi-jam/rakai-ebony/15

i try to use this

```
$this->load->helper('url');

$currentURL = current_url();

print_r($currentURL);
```

but is just get my curent url

Comment: you mean url of the previous page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644429/how-to-get-previous-page-url-in-codeigniter

Comment: Did you mean that you want the URL from which you were redirected to the current URL?

Comment: @Ghost yes but the page is 3 page before the current page

Comment: @RopAliMunshi yes but the page is 3 page before the current page

Comment: *Please refer this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135826/348234) to learn about accepting answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.*

Comment: How is "3 page before the current page" defined?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get 3 page before this page you must use session to get url that requested.

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this->load->helper('url');
$url = "";
if($this->session->set_userdata('url')){
    $url=$this->session->set_userdata('url');
}else{
    $url=[];
}
$page = current_url();
array_unshift($url, $page); 
$this->session->set_userdata('url',$url);
```

then you can simply access 3 previous url in your session or you can redirect it with below code:

```
redirect($this->session->userdata('url')[3]);
```

Comment: That array has the potential to become large unless you add some kind of mechanism to remove urls older than 3 page visits. But this is the right way to go.

Comment: @qwertzman,you right. simply you can, count of it , if larger than 3 , don't push new url to it.

Answer (score 0):

That is an odd thing you want to do. I suppose your only bet is to use sessions as PHP doesn't have a native function.

on the page 3 pages before the current page

```
$this->session->set_userdata('some_url', current_url());
```

then in the current page you can get it via `$this->session->some_url`